# Aligning text to bottom left corner inside a styled-element

Tags: html, css, text-alignment

How do I make the text that is INSIDE this styled element align to the bottom left corner?
I only want the text inside the box to be in the bottom left corner of the box. The rest of the text should be unaffected.

I am new to `CSS` and cannot figure it out.

**HTML**

```
<body>
    <h1>example text</h1>
    <article class="box" style="background-color: #2672EC">foo bar</article>
    <h1>example text</h1>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-family: Verdana;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: black;
}

.box {
    height: 187px;
    width: 187px;
    margin-right: 5.5px;
    margin-left: 5.5px;
    margin-bottom: 5.5px;
    margin-top: 5.5px;
    color: white;

}
```

Here is the JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/J9hT5/8/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it two ways, either by using CSS Positioning Technique where you need to set the parent element to `position: relative;` and the child element to `position: absolute;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9hT5/9/) *(Wrapping the text using a `span` element)*

```
.box > span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

---

Or by using `display: table-cell;` with `vertical-align: bottom;`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/J9hT5/10/) *(No change in the markup)*

```
.box {
    height: 187px;
    width: 187px;
    margin-right: 5.5px;
    margin-left: 5.5px;
    margin-bottom: 5.5px;
    margin-top: 5.5px;
    color: white;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Also, would like to refactor your CSS a bit, the below snippet

```
margin-right: 5.5px;
margin-left: 5.5px;
margin-bottom: 5.5px;
margin-top: 5.5px;
```

Can be wrote as `margin: 5.5px 5.5px 5.5px 5.5px;`

Comment: Thanks for both solutions!

Comment: Note that second option doesn't work if parent have display set to flex, unfortunately

Answer (score 3):

Try to wrap your targeted text inside a span:

```
<article class="box" style="background-color: #2672EC"><span class="bottom">foo bar</span>
```

Then you can use:

```
.box {
    position: relative;
}
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J9hT5/11/)**